# Trying to encapsulate TextInput, getting the addField error

Tags: textinput, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to encapsulate a TextInput such that when the value changes it does a serverside lookup and based on the result shows a notification to the user: "That group name already exists".  I've been using this as my example to start from: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html#the-simple-way
My current error is

> Error: The TextInput component wasn't called within a redux-form . Did you decorate it and forget to add the addField prop to your component? See https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component for details.

but even if I add in

```
NameLookupTextInput.defaultProps = {
    addField: true, // require a <Field> decoration
}
```

I still get the error. Heres my code

```
class NameLookupTextInput extends TextInput {
    handleChange = eventOrValue => {
        console.log("handleChange",eventOrValue);
        this.props.onChange(eventOrValue);
        this.props.input.onChange(eventOrValue);

        if(this.timeoutHandle){
            clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
        }
        console.log(fetch);
        this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function(){
            let value = this.props.input.value;

            fetchUtils.fetchJson(API_ENDPOINT+'/groupNameCheck/'+value, { method: 'GET'})
                .then((data) => {

                    console.log(data);
                    let exists = data.json.exists;
                    let name = data.json.name;
                    if(exists){
                        console.log(this.props.showNotification('The group name "'+name+'" already exists.'));
                    }else{
                        console.log(this.props.showNotification('The group name "'+name+'" does not exist.'));
                    }
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.error(e);
                    //showNotification('Error: comment not approved', 'warning')
                });
        }.bind(this),500);
    };

}


export default connect(null, {
    showNotification: showNotificationAction
})(NameLookupTextInput);
```

Comment: You should never *extend* a React component, but rather use *composition* instead. See https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html.